# use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm opening an modal into vue, but I'm getting the next error in console from navigator:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "showTask"

It says I should use an computed property, and I already check another solutions, but any of them can solve it because I'm using typescript, how can I use an computed property for solve it in this particular case?

in this case it is refering at the modal into my child component, the modal:

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="space-around">
    <v-col cols="auto">
      <v-dialog
        transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
        v-model="showTask"
        max-width="600"
      >
        <template>
          <!--  -->
          <v-card class="p-5">
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="8">
                <h1 class="is-size-4">Miembros del equipo</h1>
              </v-col>
              <v-col class="d-flex justify-end" cols="12" sm="4">
                <v-btn icon>
                  <v-icon aize="10" @click="showTask = false"
                    >fas fa-close</v-icon
                  >
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
              <!-- Autocomplete de usuarios -->
              <!-- nota: "Autocomplete recibe solamente un valor del objeto que se le pasa, en este caso se declara con item-value="id" -->
              <v-autocomplete
                v-model="UsersIn"
                :items="users"
                item-text="name"
                item-value="id"
                :disabled="isUpdating"
                chips
                filled
                label="Agregar Miembros"
                persistent-hint
                 multiple
              >
                <template v-slot:selection="data">
                  <!-- Chips dentro del field -->
                  <v-chip
                    v-bind="data.attrs"
                    :input-value="data.selected"
                    close
                    @click="data.select"
                    @click:close="remove(data.item)"
                  >
                    <v-avatar left>
                      <v-img :src="data.item.Photo"></v-img>
                    </v-avatar>
                    {{ data.item.name }}
                  </v-chip>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:item="data">
                  <template>
                    <v-list-item-avatar>
                      <v-avatar color="red">
                        <img :src="data.item.Photo">
                      </v-avatar>
                    </v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title
                        v-html="data.item.name"
                      ></v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle
                        v-html="data.item.group"
                      ></v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </template>
                </template>
              </v-autocomplete>
            </v-form>
            <!-- Iconos -->
          </v-card>
        </template>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
  data: () => {
     const srcs = {
        1: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg',
        2: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/2.jpg',
        3: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/3.jpg',
        4: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/4.jpg',
        5: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/5.jpg',
      }
    return {
      autoUpdate: true,
      friends: ['Sandra Adams', 'Britta Holt'],
      isUpdating: false,
      name: 'Midnight Crew',
      UsersIn: [{}],
      headers: [
        {
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: '', value: 'photo' },
        { text: '', value: 'name' },
      ],
      title: 'The summer breeze',
      users: [
        {
          initials: 'CA',
          Photo: srcs[1],
          name: 'Carlos',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          Photo: srcs[2],
          name: 'Luther',
          initials: 'Lu',
          id: 1
        },
          {
          Photo: srcs[3],
          name: 'Lutherino',
          initials: 'Lu',
          id: 3
        },
      ],
    }
  },
 watch: {
      isUpdating (val: boolean): void {
        if (val) {
          setTimeout(() => (this.isUpdating = false), 3000)
        }
      },
    },
  props: {
    showTask: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    remove (user: any) {
        var index = this.UsersIn.indexOf(user.id)
        if (index >= 0) this.UsersIn.splice(index, 1)
      },
  },
}
</script>
```

And I'm changing "showTask" status into my parent component with this method:

```
 <add-members-modal :showTask.sync="ShowModal"></add-members-modal>

 <v-btn color="#fff" elevation="0" @click="showModal"
      ><v-icon color="#000A21" class="mx-1" size="18"
        >fas fa-user-plus</v-icon
      >Añadir / 1</v-btn
    >

<script lang="ts">
       methods: {
        showModal (): void {
          this.ShowModal = false
          this.ShowModal = true
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `@click="showTask = false"` that's where you're mutating a prop directly as the warning/error is telling you to avoid

Comment: @Bravo but if I put @click="showTask = false" in parent component how I'm going to open the modal? in this case I'll be indicating it is false and child doesn't going to open  the dialog

Comment: you wouldn't put that in the parent, that makes no sense ... you want to emit an event to the parent so it can change the value of showTask

Comment: by the way - your `showModal` method is completely wrong - it always sets `this.ShowModal = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error you can use the two-way-binding concept of Vuejs.
In which you can bind the **showTask** variable of the parent component in your child component.

You can follow this article, this article has been written on the basis of this problem.

[Two way binding of dialogs in Vuejs](https://medium.com/easy-coding/two-way-binding-of-dialogs-vue-58bbae1ed4d9)

Comment: it works for me, but I added '@click:outside = "$emit('close')"' to the dialog for cover when the user makes click outside, thank you so much

Comment: answers with ONLY links to external content aren't considered good answers - why not put minimal code in your answer that demonstrates the solution

Comment: yes that could be the best in case for some reason the link is not more available in a future

Comment: Yes, you are right but this link will available because this is a medium article and I am owning this medium account. @Bravo
Thanks!